# Which one is correct? I need your help

Tags: grammar

> Don't give any ranks to people who haven't met the requirements and made a ticket.

or

> Don't give any ranks to people who haven't met the requirements and haven't made a ticket.

I want to inform my staff members that I don't want them to grant any rank/position on my discord server if the person wanting it haven't met the requirements and haven't made a ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is correct. "haven't" normally modifies only the closest phrase, not both phrases in the conjunction.

You can change this by adding "both":

> Don't give any ranks to people who haven't both met the requirements and made a ticket.

That groups the conjunction into a single item.

You can also enumerate them:

> Don't give any ranks to people who haven't: a) met the requirements and b) made a ticket.